# UnicodeEncodeError при парсинге страницы

Tags: python

При попытке спарсить web страницу выдает такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Butooz\Desktop\untitled\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(soup.findAll('a'))
  File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xab' in position 3987: character maps to <undefined>
```

Скрипт выглядит так:

```
url = 'https://aheku.net/news/'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
print(soup.findAll('a'))
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо 'request' использовать 'needle', предварительно подключив его 
    
    var needle = request('needle');

Comment: Ошибка, похоже не при парсинге, а при выводе в консоль. Автор, для этого нужно так же прикладывать стек трассы -- чтобы можно было понять где случилась ошибка :)

Comment: @gil9red, внес правку

Comment: смотрите, проблема в print, он пытался вывести в консоль, а консоль виндовая с дебильной кодировкой -- cp866, а у вас скорее всего utf-8, если не вру, то нужно декодировать в байтовую строку, а после кодировать в cp866, тогда проблем не должно возникнуть. Я с подобными случаями делал так: при выводе если ловил UnicodeEncodeError, то выводил как байтовую строку

Comment: если учесть, что я начинающий питонист, то я пока с трудом представляю себе как это реализовать в коде...

Comment: в комменте не хватило, перенес в ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите видеть что же пришло такое, то предлагаю выводить байтовую строку – к ней не будет использоваться кодирование, потому проблемы не встретится, но символы при этом будут в виде hex-чисел:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    try:
        print(a)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print(a.encode('utf-8'))
```

В примере выше мы пытаемся вывести в консоль и если не получается, выводим байтовую строку

Если вы хотите работать с данными (обработка, разбор и т.п.) проблем не будет. Они возникнут исключительно при выводе в консоль. У линуксов консоли utf-8 поддерживают и там таких проблем не будет. Если же вам нужно собирать данные, то можно вместо вывода в консоль, выводить в файл –- проблем с кодировкой не будет -- нужно при создании файла указать кодировку utf-8, иначе выберется системная, которая может отличаться.